# Add something after the "n" element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

For a markup like

```
<div id="holder">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

how do add some markup after the second DIV for instance?

Comment: Remember that eq() starts with 0 and nth-child() starts at 1, or you will become very angry.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try the [CSS selector `:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo):

```
$("#holder > div:nth-child(2)").after("<div>foobar</div>");
```

See also the example on the [jQuery page of the `:nth-child()` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild).

Answer (score 18):

use the [:eq(index)](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [:nth-child(index/even/odd/equation)](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector in combination with the [append(content)](https://api.jquery.com/append/) or [after(content)](https://api.jquery.com/after/) function.

for example, assuming this code:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

using append like this

```
$("#holder>div:eq(1)").append("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

or this

```
$("#holder>div:nth-child(2)").append("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

will give you

```
<div id="holder">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2<div>inserted div</div></div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

while using after like this

```
$("#holder>div:eq(1)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

or this

```
$("#holder>div:nth-child(2)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

will give you

```
<div id="holder">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>inserted div</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

using :nth-child can be useful as it enables you to set content every n amount of elements.
also, the index of :nth-child starts at 1 while the index of :eq starts at 0

for example, using

```
$("#holder>div:nth-child(2n)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

will give you

```
<div id="holder">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>inserted div</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
    <div>inserted div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use insertAfter(selector)

[.insertAfter()](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

Answer (score 1):

`$("#holder div:eq(1)")` will select the second child div of the `#holder` div.  ([:eq() selector info](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index)).  Then use the `.after()` function to append content.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $("ul li:nth-child(4n)").add('ul li:last').after("<div style='clear:both;'>&nbsp;</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$("#holder > div:nth-child(2n)").after("<div>insert here</div>");
```

It will insert the `<div>insert here</div>` after every 2nd row:

```
$("#holder > div:nth-child(2)").after("<div>insert here</div>");
```