# jQuery nth-child add html after

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a simple unordered list with 16 list items. I want to add a new list item after every fourth existing list item using jQuery

How would I do that? Code below:

```
<ul>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>

    <li class="clear">This is what I want to add</li>

    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>

    <li class="clear">This is what I want to add</li>

    and so on...
</ul>
```

Comment: this link very help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791943?tab=oldest

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using the `:nth-child` selector ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)):

```
$('ul li:nth-child(4n)').after('<li class="clear">This is what I want to add</li>')
```

Comment: I used like this: $('ul li:nth-child(1n)').after('<li class="sep"></li>'); But what if I don't need the .sep class LI after last LI?

Comment: Best to ask a new question, @TheHun. An easy way to do that is to remove the unwanted `li` after that. Maybe using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) will also work.