# Clearing Floats after x divs automatically with jQuery? - e.g. Varying heights break design

Tags: jquery, css

Ok, for my inner content i've got, for example a 4 x column layout - float left, set width... so they sit nicely next to each other...

Trouble is you add more elements into that set e.g. a 5th or 6th element (e.g. a new row) - ...if the first 4 columns are varying heights the the second row is all misaligned, as you would expect... So I'm writing to ask, is there a jQuery way (Or possibly something else) - That will allow you too add a "clear:both" after x amount of divs within a div (In this case clear the row after 4 divs)... Alot of the content will be pulled automatically from DB, so I don't have the option to manually add a clear:both.

Hope that makes sense, this is my first post, so please advise if i've done anything wrong, or can explain better.

Comment: Try jQuery [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery nth-child add html after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325578/jquery-nth-child-add-html-after)

Comment: I'm using a responsive layout, so won't be able to set "fixed" widths (well only for one resolution) - It looks like Masonary works out the sizeable area based on a single element (I could have a single element but with potentially 4 different sizes)

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at your suggested nth: idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div:nth-of-type(4n)').append('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, thank you, seems to work great, thanks also to mplungjan

Comment: You're welcome! Also, I'm sure you worked it out, but if not; you can replace '4n' with any number or expression you like to alter the position of the outputted HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this responsively without JS by switching to using `display: inline-block` instead of floats.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/dwbHi

```
.gallery {
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x130" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/180x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x90" />
  </div>
```