# Add div after 4 article in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add a `div` after 4 `article` in sequence.

It would look like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    **<div></div>**
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    **<div></div>**
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <h2></h2>
    <article></article>
</div>
```

I've tried many things but none of them seem to solve the problem.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery nth-child add html after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325578/jquery-nth-child-add-html-after)

Answer (score 1):

Use the nth child selector in jquery combined with after.

```
$('article:nth-child(4n)').after('')
```

Comment: The src html contains 5 `h2` tags at the same time the expected O/P contains only 4... What the..?!? So its a perfectly invalid question, OP is in a confused state.. Please ignore answering this and vote to close it..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy dude, its only a example. my code is different but I made this code for people understand it fast. If I could solve this code i posted i can solve my real code.

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos Then make sure that the question shouldn't make confusions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('article + article + article + article').after('<div> Hello </div>')
```

Comment: Is that really a jquery selector?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes.! its a valid one..!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thats nice. Its a new thing to me. What is the meaning of "+" then?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi For example `#a + #b` means select element with id b which directly follows element with id a. Its a kind of siblings selector.

Comment: No, a > div means

"Any div which is a direct descendant of a"

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

```
$(document).ready(function (){    
    var d = "<div>Data of the Page Added</div>"
    //$('div.NewsResultsList table tr:nth-child(2)').before(d); //add to before
    $('div.NewsResultsList table tr:nth-child(2)').after(d); //add to after
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/WWYp9/67/)