# The problem of running script after jquery .after use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what I want to do in general is to find the number of div on the page and place my ad codes after the number two div.

I think (.after) does not work after the code.

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
var say = $('.panel-footer.clearfix').length;
if (say >= 3) {
  $('.panel-footer.clearfix').eq(1).after(`<script async 
   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"> . 
</script>
 <ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-3767785488130692"
 data-ad-slot="3213073317"></ins>
 <script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>`);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791943/add-something-after-the-n-element-using-jquery. You can select the second element with the css element leave out the eq.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.  If you need to add additional detail to your question you may edit it to do so.  Since you're other question is more fleshed out, please delete this one.

Comment: The other is talking about a different problem. also he solved the problem. I'm trying to delete but not deleted. @Madbreaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML parser defines part of your string as a closing script tag (7th row in example).

Move your JavaScript code into .js file (this is better solution) or split script tags into separate rows (e.g. `"</scr" + "ipt>"`)

Comment: thanks for your comment how can i do this? @Eugene Voynov