# Append HTML After 2nd Paragraph of Text Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using HTML like this :

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

With jQuery like this which appends the Click Here HTML after the 1st paragraph :

```
var $this = $(this);

$this.append('<div id="link" class="link">Click Here/div>');
```

However, what i need is to append the HTML after the 2nd paragraph using `p:nth-child(2)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1791958/8079657)

Tried the following but doesn't work :

```
$this('.content p:nth-child(2)').append('<div id="link" class="link">Click Here</div>');
```

**Edit :**

```
 $('.content').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.append('<div id="link" class="link">Click Here</div>');

    $this.children('p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div class="text" />');

}
```

And wrap all remaining paragraphs in the text div ( which excludes the 1st 2 paragraphs )

Comment: What is `this` a reference to in your code?

Comment: `$(this).find('p:nth-child(2)').append('<div id="link" class="link">Click Here</div>');`

Comment: Added the full code as a Edit.

Comment: Thank you. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. You need to use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) as follows:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.content').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
  
    $this.children('p:nth-child(2)').append('<div id="link" class="link">Click Here</div>');

    $this.children('p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div class="text" />');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use the $this variable. See Edit.

Comment: @Michelle please see the edit. For what it's worth, it's more efficient to use the original answer, rather than looping over each `.content` element.

Comment: This adds the HTML link after the 1st paragraph, not the 2nd.

Comment: @Michelle no, it doesn't. Please run the snippet.

Comment: @Michelle, I've updated the snippet to use all of your code, and you can see it working as expected...

Comment: The last line doesn't wrap the paragraphs ( excluding the first 2 paragraphs ) in a text div therefore doesn't work.

Comment: @Michelle yes, it does. Please look at the generated source: `<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <div class="text"><p>Paragraph 2<div id="link" class="link">Click Here</div></p><p>Paragraph 3</p></div></div>`

Comment: Only the first paragraph is excluded when it needs to exclude the first 2 and wrap paragraph 3 and greater

Comment: @Michelle, that is a completely different issue to the one raised in your original question. Please ask a separate question, instead of moving the goalposts on one which has a valid answer. FWIW, your issue is with the selector in your original quote: `p:not(:first-child)`. Hope that gives you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looping through the `.content` elements as there are multiple instances of them. This is not necessary as jQuery will automatically do this for you if the selector contains a collection of elements. You then simply need to call `append()` to add the content in the required location. Try this:

```js
$('.content p:nth-child(2)').append('<div id="link" class="link">Click Here</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div> 
<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to use .append not .after.

Comment: So you want the `div` to appear within the `p`?

Comment: Ok, apologies for the misunderstanding. I've updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some part of code for demonstration. Check out this code:

```
$.each($('.content p'), function (index, paragraph) {
    if (index == 1) { //second element
      $(paragraph).append('<div>some text</div>');
    }
});
```

Working jsFiddle: **[CLICK!](https://jsfiddle.net/6xpz97Lf/2/)**

Comment: This really isn't very performan at all. Why not leverage the power of Sizzle?

Comment: I only show different approach for solve OP problem.